# Can't import ng2 service unless use specific capitalization

Tags: angular, capitalization

I have created a service in file 'myapi.service.ts' which contains:

```
export class MyAPIService {
```

and in my component I import the service as follows:

```
import { MyAPIService } from '../myapi.service';
```

But everytime I compile I get this error:

> Module '"/myapi.service"' has no exported member
>   'MyAPIService'.

The problem seems to be capitalizatio.n  If I import "MyapiService" instead of "MyAPIService" then it compiles fine.  But why?  Does ng2 require/force certain capitalization?  Shouldn't it use the capitalization I used when creating the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a thing in Angular or TypeScript. Make sure there is no other mistake somewhere in your code.

[Here's a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6vrfvk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Maybe also (although this is a real edge case), check your webpack config if there's anything going super crazy in there, or you played with the `paths` property of tsconfig, but most likely it's a much simpler mistake in your code.

Maybe you needed to restart your build watch / dev server too or so as well.

### Update

If this is an external dependency (NPM module), then try removing your `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again.

As in comments, this was the case for the OP.

Comment: I tried restarting 'ng serve' but no change.  Where is the webpack config file?

Comment: I found the webpack config and it looks fine.  Is there a way to tell ng to recreate any config/other files for the project?  I did move the project to another directory and I'm wonder if that affected something

Comment: I removed the node_modules directory and then did a 'npm i' to recreate the folder.  After that things started to work.  I'll accept your answer as this should steer other users to the right solution.  (Or add this to your answer)

Comment: I originally thought this was in your code because of the `../`, but this makes total sense. The answer has been updated. Thanks for accepting it.